# CSS gradient cruzado de arriba a abajo con derecha a izquierda

Tags: css, css3

Lo que estoy intentando es que el color negro a cierta distancia (col-lg-2 en Bootstrap) que son 16.6666666% se difumine con el azul, es decir, que el negro se vaya combinando con el azul la tonalidad diferente azul en el otro lado.

¿Es posible hacer esta locura?

Tengo este código

```
body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#50a1ce,#020822);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#50a1ce,#020822);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#50a1ce,#020822);
    background: linear-gradient(#50a1ce,#020822);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right,#171616 16.66666%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right,#171616 16.66666%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right,#171616 16.66666%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,#171616 16.66666%);
}
```

Esta es mi pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar `background-blend-mode` para mezclar backgrounds, no estoy seguro del efecto que quieres lograr, pero existen distintos efectos de mezcla,  te dejo un efecto con `multiply`

```css
div{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0;    
  background: linear-gradient(to right,#171616 16%, #FFFFFF), linear-gradient(#50a1ce,#020822);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió bastante.